# JavaScript Promises - Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, promise

`getId` results in an error **Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**. It is returning the `Promise.resolve(r)` before waiting for the `fetchIDs` promise to be resolved (GET request is done ).

```
function fetchIDs () {
  return new Promise (function (resolve, reject){
    // GET request
  });
};

function getId () {
  if (typeof localStorage.id !== 'undefined' ) {
    return Promise.resolve(localStorage.id);
  }
  else {
    fetchIDs().then(function (r) {
      return Promise.resolve(r);
    });
  }
};

getId().then(function (r) {
    localStorage.id = r;
    doSthElse();
});
```

Any idea what am I missing or doing wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: getId returns nothing if there's nothing in localstorage.

Comment: I should edit that, it works fine with first condition. the problem occurs when useing fetchIDs().then

Comment: You're not returning the value of `fetchIDs().then`. You're just invoking it. Change to `return fetchIDs().then...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getId()` does not return anything if you end up calling `fetchIDs()`.  You can change it to be like this:

```
function getId () {
  if (typeof localStorage.id !== 'undefined' ) {
    return Promise.resolve(localStorage.id);
  }
  else {
    return fetchIDs().then(function (r) {
      return Promise.resolve(r);
    });
  }
};
```

But, you don't actually need the extra `Promise.resolve(r)` and can just do this:

```
function getId () {
  if (typeof localStorage.id !== 'undefined' ) {
    return Promise.resolve(localStorage.id);
  }
  else {
    return fetchIDs();
  }
};
```

That will return the promise from `fetchIDs()` which the caller of `getId()` can then use.

Comment: Yep, you're right, a silly mistake I must admit. I've fixed it since Brian have pointed it out in the comments. Thanks a bunch.